# How to compile the android kernel correctly without errors

Tags: android, linux, makefile

I've been trying to build the kernel for a week now, but it doesn't work, errors are flying out, I tried to fumble with the makefile, change gcc and clang, tried to build it on mint linux, on kali linux, it didn't help me!

**here is the Output**
[image: What did make output]